# Searching list by LastIndex in loop.

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to complete an algorithm that adds ProcTime to a max of two other max values (JobNumMax and WSMax). I am having trouble using the FindLastIndex and FindLast in my loops. 
Here is my code.

```
public class JobListOrder
        {
            public int JobNum { get; set; }
            public string Workstation { get; set; }
            public int Sequence { get; set; }
            public int ProcTime { get; set; }
            public int EndHour { get; set; }
            public DateTime DueDate { get; set; } 
            public int Priority { get; set; } 
        }
```

Putting into list.

```
//New List
            List<JobListOrder> list = new List<JobListOrder>();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Nathan\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\PubsExample\\PubsExample\\JobsList.txt"))
            {
                //Add .txt to List
                while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    string str;
                    string [] strArray;
                    str = sr.ReadLine();

                    strArray = str.Split(',');
                    JobListOrder currentjob = new JobListOrder();
                    currentjob.JobNum = int.Parse(strArray[0]);
                    currentjob.Workstation = strArray[1];
                    currentjob.Sequence = int.Parse(strArray[2]);
                    currentjob.ProcTime = int.Parse(strArray[3]);
                    currentjob.EndHour = int.Parse(strArray[4]);
                    currentjob.DueDate = DateTime.Parse(strArray[5]);
                    currentjob.Priority = int.Parse(strArray[6]);
                    list.Add(currentjob);

                }
```

Sort into a particular way to start calculations

```
 //Job Sort
                var ListSort = from jobsort in list
                               orderby jobsort.Sequence ascending, jobsort.Priority descending, jobsort.DueDate ascending, jobsort.JobNum ascending
                               select jobsort;
                List<JobListOrder> SortList = new List<JobListOrder>(ListSort);
```

Here is a slight attempt at it

```
//foreach (var i in SortList)
                //{
                //    if (JobNumMax >= WSMax)
                //    {
                //        return i.EndHour = JobNumMax + i.ProcTime;
                //    }
                //    else
                //        return i.EndHour = WSMax + currentjob.ProcTime;
                //    for (var j = 0; j < SortList.Count; j++)
                //    {
                //        int JobLNumMaxIndex = SortList.FindLastIndex(i.JobNum)
                //        int JobNumMax = i.EndHour[JobNumMaxIndex];
                //        for (var k = 0; k < SortList.Count; k++)
                //        {
                //            int WSMaxIndex = SortList.FindLastIndex(i.Workstation);
                //            int WSMax = i.EndHour[JobNumMaxIndex];

                //        }
                //    }

                //}
```

I am trying to find the LastIndex of a query and return a value of that particular index. I'll try to explain what I mean in the code below Searching for JobNum = 1 and Workstation = Milling with a ProcTime of 1

```
            foreach (var i in SortList) //Iterate through SortList
            {
                if (JobNumMax (3) >= WSMax (4)) 
                {
                    return i.EndHour = JobNumMax (3) + i.ProcTime (1); //assigns calculation to EndHour of current record
                }
                else
                    return i.EndHour = WSMax (4) + i.ProcTime (1);
                for (var j = 0; j < SortList.Count; j++)
                {
                    int JobLNumMaxIndex = SortList.FindLastIndex(1) //Finds last record with JobNum = 1
                    int JobNumMax = i.EndHour[JobNumMaxIndex];//Return what EndHour is at the index from JobNumMaxIndex search// Lets say 3
                    for (var k = 0; k < SortList.Count; k++)
                    {
                        int WSMaxIndex = SortList.FindLastIndex(Milling);//Finds last record with Workstation = Milling
                        int WSMax = i.EndHour[JobNumMaxIndex];//Return what EndHour is at the index from WSMaxIndex search// Lets say 4

                    }
                }

            }
```

Result would be 4 + 1 = 5.

I am having trouble with syntax of the algorithm. I can't get the FindLast to work at all.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might just be having trouble with the LINQ syntax.

`FindLastIndex` will take a `Predicate<JobListOrder>` as an argument, i.e, a function which takes a `JobListOrder` as an input an returns true or false.

So instead of `SortList.FindLastIndex(i.JobNum)` you should probably have something like:

```
SortList.FindLastIndex(order => order.JobNum == i.JobNum);
```

Corrected in your code:

```
int JobNumMax = 0;
int WSMax  0;

foreach (var i in SortList)
{
    if (JobNumMax >= WSMax)
    {
        return i.EndHour = JobNumMax + i.ProcTime;
    }
    else if (JobNumMax > 0 && WSMax > 0)
    {
        return i.EndHour = WSMax + currentjob.ProcTime;
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < SortList.Count; j++)
    {
        int JobLNumMaxIndex = SortList.FindLastIndex(order => order.JobNum == i.JobNum);
        JobNumMax = i.EndHour[JobNumMaxIndex];

        for (var k = 0; k < SortList.Count; k++)
        {
            int WSMaxIndex = SortList.FindLastIndex(order => order.Workstation == i.Workstation);
            WSMax = i.EndHour[JobNumMaxIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. That worked for those FindLastIndex issues. I guess I have another issue. In the int JobNumMax = i.EndHour[JobNumMaxIndex]; it says that apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'int'. I may be overseeing something but it also doesn't recognize JobNumMax or WSMax in the current context in the If/else statement.

Comment: I've made a change to the code to move the declarations outside of the loop - as previously they were only scoped to the inner loops. I'm a bit confused as to why you're using a loop though as it only ever seems to be going to loop once and then return due to the first if statement. If you edit your question to show some sample inputs and the desired output from the function it may be easier to help.